# Are Data Source Names (DSN's) relative to the system referencing it?

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, dsn

This may be a simple yes/no answer. I have a classic ASP file opening a `ADODB` connection to an access database via an `ODBC` string that references a `DSN`. I believe however that the `DSN` has to be known to the `IIS` machine where the ASP is running, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically just a

> *"Yes it is correct"*

answer, but to try and explain a little why this is the case.

In a Windows environment [DSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_source_name) is just another form of connection string that is stored inside the Windows Registry or File System and are managed by a program called `ODBC Datasource Administrator` *(`odbcad32.exe`)*.

If you are working with IIS and the web application contains references to DSN then you will likely find them inside the `System DSN` tab in the `ODBC Datasource Administrator`. There is however one caveat to this and that is with the surge of 64 Bit Operating Systems and how accessing DSNs is affected.

---

#### Where is `odbcad32.exe` Located?

1. Is the Machines Window Operating System 64 Bit?

   - Yes - Go to point 2.
   - No

     ```
     %SystemRoot%\System32\odbcad32.exe
     ```
2. Is the Web Appication running in `32 Bit Mode`?

   - Yes

     ```
     %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
     ```
   - No

     ```
     %SystemRoot%\System32\odbcad32.exe
     ```